# Y a-t-il une expression alternative pour « lecteur réseau » ?

Tags: terminologie, informatique

Je suis à la recherche d'expressions françaises courantes pour « *network drive* » (anglais) ou « *Netzlaufwerk* » (allemand).

Google Translate le traduit par « lecteur réseau » pour l'[anglais](http://translate.google.com/#en/fr/Do%20you%20have%20a%20network%20drive%20that%20everyone%20has%20access%20to?) et l'[allemand](http://translate.google.com/#de/fr/Haben%20Sie%20ein%20Netzlaufwerk?), mais est-ce que des alternatives existent, qui seraient comprises par des gens peu doués techniquement ?

L'idée est surtout d'avoir des alternatives à la main en parlant avec des clients. La majorité d'eux sont des médecins et ne comprennent pas grand-chose de l'informatique. Lecteur réseau me parait trop technique. (Je ne suis pas de langue maternelle française.)

**Complément :**
Mes clients travaillent dans des entreprises de tailles différentes. Ils partagent certains dossiers sur le réseau l'un avec l'autre. (Cela veut dire que les dossiers sont joignables à partir de n'importe quel ordinateur d'un membre du groupe.)

J'aimerais leur demander : « Do you have a network drive? ». La première possibilité serait de demander : « Avez-vous un lecteur réseau ?»

Comment: _Lecteur réseau_ est très connoté Microsoft.

Comment: C'est difficile de choisir une réponse. Il n'y a apparemment pas un terme qui serait convenable pour tout le monde. J'aime bien « disque réseau » et « serveur ». J'ai édité ma question pour donner encore de contexte.

Comment: La question est aussi peu claire en anglais qu'en français. Si tu sais qu'il existe un système de partage, qu'espères-tu savoir ? Si c'est un point technique dépendant du système d'exploitation, il n'y a pas trente-six solutions, il faut utiliser la traduction française utilisée par ce système.

Comment: Si l'anglais n'est pas ta langue maternelle, n'hésite pas à décrire ici ce que tu entends par *network drive*, ça nous sera beaucoup plus facile de te trouver une traduction adéquate!

Comment: Selon mon expérience récente, les termes « dossier partagé » et « disque réseau » sont mieux compris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans le cadre de mon travail, pour désigner un espace où des personnes distantes peuvent partager des fichiers, je préfère le terme **dossier partagé**.

Peu importe ce qui est physiquement derrière, pour l'utilisateur c'est effectivement un dossier dont le contenu est partagé entre plusieurs personnes.

Cette expression semble être utilisée dans divers environnements : Windows, Ubuntu, mais aussi Virtualbox et même Dropbox.

Avec le même adjectif, l'expression **disque partagé** me parait également acceptable, bien que plus technique.

Comment: Personnellement je n'aime pas. Le concepte de "Partagé" est déjà utilisé dans le cadre des "Permissions". Dire qu'un dossier est partagé n'indique aucunement qu'il se trouve sur un réseau. Exemple: Sur mon poste, j'ai des dossiers partagés, ce qui fait en sorte que su un autre utilisateur ouvre une session sur mon poste, il y a accès. C'est donc un Dossier Partagé, local. Si à la maison j'ai un NAS, ce n'est pas un dossier partagé, et il est pourtant sur le réseau.

Comment: @Tipx: La question stipule: "Ils partagent certains dossiers sur le réseau l'un avec l'autre". Utiliser le mot "réseau" dans la réponse n'est pas une obligation, c'est même préjudiciable puisqu'il s'agit d'un terme technique. Je suis sûr que pour ces médecins le terme "partager" n'évoque pas le concept de permissions (même si les informaticiens parmi nous comprendront qu'il faudra qu'un technicien mette en place certaines permissions, effectivement, mais les médecins n'en savent rien).

Comment: J'ai pas envie d'argumenter, mais de renommer un concept simplement car "l'audience" ne le comprend est pas une chose à faire; c'est ce qu'on appel du nivellement par le bas.

Answer (score 5):

Je traduirais plutôt *network drive* par *unité de stockage réseau* ou *disque réseau*. Pour ce qui est des utilisateurs non habitués aux termes techniques, mais familiarisés avec l'utilisation de ce *network drive*, il est probable qu'ils utilisent déjà le terme *serveur*, qui pour eux restera cette boîte noire accessible par l'ensemble des utilisateurs connectés au réseau.

L'expression *lecteur réseau* semble plutôt indiquer qu'il s'agit d'un lecteur optique disponible sur le réseau.

Comment: *Unité de stockage réseau* ? pour des néophytes ?

Comment: Si ça ne tenait qu'à moi, je ne laisserai même pas savoir aux néophytes si le disque est en réseau ou local...

Comment: Ok on se comprend ;-) et effectivement *disque réseau* passe aussi.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne sais toujours pas quel est l'objet ou le concept que tu souhaites désigner. Probablement l'une des possibilités suivantes:

1. Peut-être fais-tu simplement référence à la terminologie des systèmes d'exploitation Microsoft pour *le point de montage* d'un système de fichiers partagé. Dans ce cas « ***lecteur réseau*** » (*network drive*) est le seul choix possible. Il ne parait pas raisonnable d'inventer une nouvelle dénomination.
2. Peut-être souhaites-tu de façon générale désigner un « ***système de fichiers partagé*** » (*network file system*), potentiellement hébergé sur un « *serveur* » (*server*). Si c'est bien de cela dont il s'agit, ces termes parlent bien plus que des concepts comme « lecteur » ou « disque », qu'on ferait mieux de n'utiliser que pour ce qu'ils désignent vraiment. La dénomination « ***dossier partagé*** » est également courante, mais il s'agit techniquement du partage d'une sous-partie d'un autre système de fichiers. À noter que les utilisateurs du « dossier partagé », à l'exception de celui qui l'a mis en place, ne savent pas forçément que c'en est un.
3. Tu parles peut-être d'une « ***unité de stockage distante*** » que j'ai déjà vu employé pour désigner un appareil ou un système accessible au travers du réseau, qui permet de stocker des données. En particulier, il peut s'agir d'un simple « ***disque dur*** (*accessible en*) ***réseau*** » autonome (*network hard drive*) ; c'est la dénomination utilisée dans les commerces pour un disque dur externe qui est accessible *over Ethernet* :

   [image: disque dur réseau]
4. Je n'y crois pas trop, mais il se pourrait aussi que tu veuilles effectivement désigner un *appareil* désigné « ***lecteur réseau*** », la terminologie est assez floue, mais en cherchant un peu on trouve généralement des lecteurs multimédia avec lesquels on peut communiquer via le réseau (WiFi ou Ethernet). Des machins comme ça :

   [image: lecteur réseau]

Answer (score 4):

(Résumé de la réponse : les alternatives à *lecteur réseau* embrouillent plus qu'elles ne clarifient la compréhension)

**Lecteur réseau** est également le choix de traduction qu'a fait Microsoft pour l'interface française de Windows. Ce qui n'en fait pas un canon, mais étant donné le contexte de ta demande, si on s'adresse à des utilisateurs non-techniciens et qu'on commence à employer des termes différents de ceux avec lesquels ils vont interagir, il me semble qu'on court dans le mur à toute vitesse.

---

Simple remarque : mais j'avoue que je saisis mal comment des personnes ignorant le *concept même de lecteur réseau* vont trouver clair un terme (périphrases descriptives à part, bien entendu) pour le désigner, quel qu'il soit. Le mot *habit* serait-il plus simple à comprendre que *vêtement* pour quelqu'un ne connaissant pas leur sens ? Il me semble qu'on touche à l'aspect conventionnel du langage, ne tombons pas dans le nominalisme...

Comment: Pas de proposition pour aider l'auteur de la question ?

Comment: Elle est en gras. :-) Il me semble que c'est le meilleur choix, si c'est bien l'objet du débat. On pourrait reformuler ma réponse en disant *les alternatives sont moins bonnes que l'original de l'énoncé.*

Comment: Ok. Je ne suis pas sûr qu'un néophyte comprenne cette expression.

Comment: @Zistoloen Donc tu penses qu'il existe un mot qui permette à un néophyte d'apprendre *ce qu'est* un lecteur réseau ?

Comment: Cela dépend du degré de connaissances informatiques du néophyte. S'il ne connait rien du tout, je suis d'accord avec ta réponse. S'il connait un peu l'informatique je préfère ma réponse.

Answer (score 2):

Si le but est de s'adresser à des non connaisseurs, je me limiterais à un *stockage externe* qui s'affranchit de tous les mots liés au jargon informatique.

Comment: (+1) Le seul danger éventuel est la polysémie du mot externe (*Ah bon ? Vous avez des ordinateurs étanches sur le toit du batiment ?*). Mais je trouve la réponse très bonne.

Comment: -1, *stockage externe* est un terme déjà souvent utilisé pour désigner cartes mémoires et autres clés USB

Comment: @AlexisPigeon : carte mémoire, clés USB, disque USB, disque réseau... pour un néophyte c'est un peu la même chose, non ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tout d'abord, *network drive* se traduit *disque réseau* en français.

Maintenant, si je m'adressais à des personnes peu douées techniquement, je dirai :

> Disque dur sur le réseau informatique

En effet, le terme *disque dur* est compris par de nombreuses personnes connaissant peu l'informatique.

Comment: Un disque dur sur le réseau informatique ? Je dirais sans trop me mouiller qu'il doit surement y en avoir un quelque part :-)